# json_parse function working very slow in IE7

Tags: javascript, json, internet-explorer

I'm using json_parse function to parse the data that I get back from an Ajax call.  This works very well in FF, but not so in IE7.  It is very very slow, and sometimes it just freezes the browser.  For various reasons, I can't change the logic of the app.  Is there any way to fix it?

The response from the ajax call is very big, and thats the reason IE7 chokes

Comment: Don't think so. Pass a smaller json object.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `eval` will be faster, but less secure.

Comment: it doesn't work, I tried.  My return data has some HTML too, so eval seems to fail

Comment: Try wrapping it in `"(" + str + ")"`.